# Where to start understanding Xbox APIs

Tags: rest, xbox

For context: I am trying to build a little script just for learning that gets all my unlocked achievements on Xbox Live. The official Xbox Services API documentation is...let's just say it's not for beginners. It makes it seem like you need to be building a game to have access to the API - maybe I'm understanding it wrong, but fair enough.

There is also a RESTful interface: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/gdk/_content/gc/reference/live/gc-reference-live-toc but I don't see how I could call it without the authorization workflow and a API key which I don't know how to get.

I've then found this unofficial API https://xbl.io that is quite easy to use. You get an API key, give permissions for xbl.io to access Xbox Live data and presto you have what you need.

My question/challenge is, how does xbl.io work? Does it integrate the official XSAPI somehow?

Thanks!

I don't even know where to begin working with the official XSAPI.

Comment: Take a look at this part of the documentation and see if it is closer to what you expect. This provides the URI you'll require and defines all the parameters that are accepted https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/gdk/_content/gc/reference/live/rest/uri/achievements/uri-achievementsusersxuidachievementsgetv2

To answer your second question, yes, the xbl.io API will just have implementations of the regular xbox endpoints with names and parameters that are more relevant to an end-user like you or I, as opposed to a game developer.

Comment: Thanks Stitt, I did look at that, and it does feel like it's close to what I want. But I can't wrap my head around what the whole code would look like. How would I authenticate the user beforehand?